# Page Refreshes even with a return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a simple HTML5 canvas exercise and ran into a bit of a snag. I cannot get the page to stop refreshing even after a return false in the checkAnswer function. I have searched high and low for the answer and have tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have created a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/geekch1ck/ezSyf/

I also don't understand the "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" on JSFiddle.

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm sure I'm missing something rather simple, but I can't find it in any of the books or sites I've combed over.

Here is the code for those who don't want to mess with JSFiddle

```
 function getRandInt (min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)) + min;
    }

    function checkAnswer(guess, answer){
    if (guess == answer){
        alert("Correct");
        setTimeout(drawText(equation),3000);
        return true;
        }
    else{
        alert("Try Again");
        return false;
        }
    }

    function drawCanvas(equation){
    //draw the Canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    drawText(equation);
    }

    function drawText(equation){
    //add the text to the canvas
    context.font = '40pt Veranda';
    context.fillText(equation, 50, 100);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    drawCanvas(equation);

    $("form").submit(function(){
        guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
        checkAnswer(guess, answer);
        });

    });



    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "200" height = "200" style = "border:1px solid   #000000;">
    </canvas>

<form action="">
<p>What is the answer? <input type = "text" id = "guess" name = "guess"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really !!! -> http://jsfiddle.net/ezSyf/2/

Comment: Even added some recursion of the calculation -> http://jsfiddle.net/ezSyf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps not returning the return value of checkAnswer? Maybe it should be:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    return checkAnswer(guess, answer);
});
```

Comment: That is it! I figured it was something rather simple, but it was stumping me to no end. Thank you so very much.